# Bypass native variables sorting in a batch FOR loop

Tags: sorting, batch-file, cmd

I need to read an arbitrary number of variable "names" from one file, and later assign them "values" supplied by another file, with both sources not available at once. I tried using the code below, but the problem is, SET command natively sorts variables alphabetically, thus preventing correct value assignments. Is there an alternative approach to set variables in this case, or a way to block native Cmd vars sorting by SET? I don't want setting numbered variable arrays if possible, as they complicate the code by adding extra layer of variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1" %%i in (%args1_file%) do (
    set "%%i=0" & set "%%i=_%%i")
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%i in ('set _') do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%j in (%args2_file%) do (
    set "%%i=%%j"
    if not !%%i! equ 0 (echo %%i = %%j
    ) else (set /p "%%j=Enter %%i > " 2>nul)
    call :validate
)

:: more code using vars %%i

exit /b

:validate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the approach that doesn't use a numbered array to read var names and values from separate files, and won't cause vars sorting to ensure correct value assignments:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1" %%i in (%args1_file%) do (
    set "%%i=0" & set "vars=!vars! _%%i")
for %%i in (!vars!) do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%j in (%args2_file%) do (
        if not %%j.==. set %%i=%%j)
    if not !%%i! equ 0 (echo %%i = %%j
    ) else (set /p "%%j=Enter %%i > " 2>nul)
    call :validate
)

:: more code using vars %%i

exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the sorted order returned by `set`, there's no way around it.

It's not documented anywhere I can see, but the environment variable block maintained by `GetEnvironmentStrings()` and friends is maintained in sorted order, at least in every NT OS I've seen, and probably before then.  When you add a new string to it's list, it's added in sorted position, so the order of addition is lost by the system.

I think you can set the variables based off names in one file with values in another file by:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _i=0

for /f "tokens=1" %%i in (names.txt) do (
    set _val_!_i!=%%i
    set /a _i=!_i!+1
)

set _i=0

for /f "tokens=1" %%i in (vals.txt) do (
    set _temp=_val_!_i!
    call set __%%!_temp!%%=%%i
    set /a _i=!_i!+1
)

echo one == !__one!
echo two == !__two!
echo three == !__three!
```

Comment: If vars sorting by SET can't be blocked, there might be another approach to set variables in the above scenario without invoking numbered arrays?

Comment: With some syntax that always makes my head hurt, it's not too hard, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, that should work. Yet it still uses a numbered array internally. :)